# iShowu alternative for windows

Tags: windows, mac, screen-capture, screencasts

What are some good alternatives for something like [iShowu](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/) which [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/about) uses for recording the screen?

Apart from good quality I am looking for other features like one click publishing to youtube or other video hosting services.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://alternativeto.net/software/ishowu-hd/?platform=windows) list of possible windows alternatives of iShowU